# How to move elements without being child like jQuery append()?

Tags: jquery

```
function moveAround(){
$('p').append($('#div'));
}
```

Above code will move "div" after "p" element as a child. I don't want like that. I just want "div" append after "p" but still same level with "p". What shall I do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`after`](http://api.jquery.com/after)

```
function moveAround(){
  $('p').after($('#div'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you [read the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/)? See `.after()` and `.before()`.